# I can't exit out of python on CMD using ctrl + c

Tags: python, cmd.exe

When I was trying python on cmd prompt and I was trying to exit to install a package, the sentence "keyboard interrupt" was displayed instead of actually exiting. I couldn't find a "break" key to try ctrl + break, so I kept trying with ctrl + c. I tried the default settings, removing the quick edit mode, and run as administrator, I just can't seem to exit out of python.

Any help with this problem would be much appreciated.

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35695388/10765659)?

Comment: Thank you so much, @KamilMaciorowski ! It worked. But I am just annoyed that ctrl + c didn't work.

Comment: I would expect Ctrl+d but I know neither Python nor `cmd.exe`.

Comment: Ctrl-C does not break out of simple Terminal in Kali, so I expect it is just the way Linux is

Answer (score 6, accepted):

On Windows, in the interactive Python interpreter, the options to exit are:

- `quit()`
- `exit()`
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Z</kbd> then <kbd>Enter</kbd>
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Break</kbd>

When running scripts, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd> can generally be used to send a `KeyboardInterrupt` that halts script execution (note that a Traceback will be generated).

---

*The <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Break</kbd> option assumes your keyboard has a <kbd>Break</kbd> or <kbd>Pause/Break</kbd> key.*

Answer (score 1):

On Linux, you can use

- the commands `quit()` or `exit()`
- or the key combination <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd>

Pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> in the Python Interpreter only causes a *KeyboardInterrupt* exception.
Pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Break</kbd> in Linux does nothing relevant in regard to the Python shell.
Pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd> merely stops and puts the Python process to the background without ending it.

Comment: I'm a Linux guy and I find normal that *interactive* interpreters (e.g. shells) use Ctrl+D for this, not Ctrl+C. I think even `cmd.exe` in Windows doesn't exit on Ctrl+C. Why should Python differ? In this context "unknown reason" seems unjustified.

Comment: It could be that the process running the python interpreter at least originally needed a quit option as well, thus CTRL-C would be ambiguous if used for both the interpreter and the host program?

Comment: Which design decision exactly? What's the rationale?

Comment: I reworded the whole answer.