# Ctrl + D not working to exit Command Prompt nor Anaconda Powershell from Python

Tags: python, cmd.exe, anaconda

Ctrl + D no longer works to exit command prompt nor Anaconda Powershell when I'm in python. All it does is "^D". It worked when I first downloaded Anaconda for Python use. I've tested Ctrl + D in other applications such as Excel and Word and it works as intended.

I thought it was maybe something to do with Windows computers because I saw the following, "In Linux and MacOS environments, you can terminate standard input by outputting EOF (end of file) using the CTRL-D keyboard shortcut. In Windows, the CTRL-D key combination does not do the same. Lets look at how to accomplish this in Windows Command Prompt or Powershell." posted on this website - https://www.devdungeon.com/content/windows-eof-ctrl-d-equivalent

BUT, I had buddy of mine in one of my University classes do Ctrl + D to exit the python program thing and it worked for him. He has Windows 10 with Python 3.8.5

I know it worked about a week ago because that is when we downloaded Anaconda as a class and started to write some simple Python code.

*Screen shot of Anaconda PowerShell and example of trying to exit Python 3.8.5*

[image: Screen shot of Anaconda PowerShell and example of trying to exit Python 3.8.5]

Thanks for any advice or help!

Answer (score 1):

> I thought it was maybe something to do with Windows computers[.]

My understanding is that <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> typically only works with Python under *Nix-like operating systems.

> I know it worked about a week ago because that is when we downloaded Anaconda as a class and started to write some simple Python code.

If it worked previously, then something has changed but it might be difficult to pin down what. Notably, however, I recieve the same output as your screenshot with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd>, so it seems like some information is missing here.

> I had buddy of mine in one of my University classes do Ctrl + D to exit the python program thing and it worked for him. He has Windows 10 with Python 3.8.5.

Again, there is likely something missing from this recollection then, as plain <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> doesn't normally exit the Python interpreter in a standard Windows command prompt (verified with the latest vanilla versions of Python 2.7, 3.6, 3.7 and 3.8).

As a total guess, perhaps your friend was working with Python in Linux via the [Windows Subsystem for Linux](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/about) (WSL) available in Windows 10 (possibly making <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> an option to exit the interpreter).

In any case, if you need a list of other options to exit the interpreter under Windows, I would suggest you see [this answer](https://superuser.com/a/1523985/302907).

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why CTRL+D doesn't work in some environments. But in those cases, I use the Python function `exit()` and it has the same effect.